# C++ Data type error while building glow compiler

Tags: python, c++, cmake, llvm, glow

I am getting the following error while i am compiling glow

```
/Users/dhruva_macintosh/Calligo/glow/lib/Graph/Nodes.cpp:2252:14: error: no matching function for call to 'expectCompareTrue'
  isValid &= expectCompareTrue(
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/dhruva_macintosh/Calligo/glow/include/glow/Graph/VerifierHelper.h:126:6: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter 'InputTy' ('unsigned long' vs. 'unsigned long long')
bool expectCompareTrue(
     ^
/Users/dhruva_macintosh/Calligo/glow/include/glow/Graph/VerifierHelper.h:154:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'ArrayRef<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'unsigned long long'
bool expectCompareTrue(
     ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [lib/Graph/CMakeFiles/Graph.dir/Nodes.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [lib/Graph/CMakeFiles/Graph.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

llvm-g++ version

```
Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I am using MacOS 12.4, Intel processor

Github link of compiler: https://github.com/pytorch/glow

More Details of error: https://github.com/pytorch/glow/issues/5989

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you compiling a particular release of glow? The main branch?

Comment: I am compiling the main branch....